# Data size of my SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I want to build a SELECT query based off one of my user generated tables 'mxsec.secmaster' where I can measure the size of the SELECT statement?

An example of the query would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM MXSEC.SECMASTER 
WHERE SECKEY = 4
```

What is the best way to find out the amount of data that is being returned in that select statement? Should I use system tables? Should I include client statistics?

Comment: You can use `count(*)` if you want the number of rows.  Please explain what  results you actually want.

Comment: I would like to know in MB's, how much the select query is pulling from the database.

Comment: @Bmore813 . . . You do realize that this only has a loose correlation with the amount of data it will occupy in the application.

Comment: Why? What could you possibly need this information for?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
INTO t1
FROM MXSEC.SECMASTER 
WHERE SECKEY = 4

EXEC sp_spaceused 'T1'
DROP TABLE T1
```

gives results such as:

```
 name   rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
 ----  -------  ---------   ------- ----------- ------
 t1     18304   8912 KB     8848 KB 8 KB         56 KB
```

> EDIT

If you cannot create permament tables you could try temporary tables:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #t1
FROM MXSEC.SECMASTER 
WHERE SECKEY = 4
```

`dbcc showcontig ('tempdb.dbo.#t1') with tableresults`

Alternatively if you are happy to do this through SSMS then you could include Client Statistics in your query execution options Query Menu / Include Client Statistics and then look at bytes received from the server, this will include network overhead but might eb sufficient for your needs.

Comment: That works, but I can only run a select statement. I do not have permissions to drop a table. Do you know of another way?

Comment: See my update with a number of additional options.

Comment: that helps a lot. Thank you very much.